# How to copy data from another workbook according to Inputbox and cell coordinates?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and need help to work on a code that will automatically synthesize data from other workbooks.

The idea is that I have different files for each month (e.g. 2019-04) and in each file there are several workbooks for the different portfolios that I need to deal with.

I am looking to synthesize the data in the following way: each row represents a portfolio and the columns represent the data I wish to copy from other files. Every 7 columns are specific to one particular month.

In the code I have so far, I prompt the user to enter the date of the portfolio under the following form : YYYY-MM ; I then want to find the column of the cell that has this particular date (this part I haven’t been able to figure out yet).

I then use a loop that will open every workbook from which I want to copy the information.

And finally, it will copy the data from every workbook based on the row of the portfolio and the column of the date.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have only just found out about VBA so I h=am not yet very familiar with all the tricks and tips.

Here is what I have so far (note that I have not entered all 7 values I want to copy):

```
Sub StressTest()

Dim index As Integer
Dim dateColumn As Integer
Dim portfolioName As Variant
Dim portfolioDate As Variant

portfolioDate = InputBox("Please enter date under the following form : YYYY-MM", "Date at the time of Stress Test", "Type Here")
For index = 3 To 39

portfolioName = Range("A" & index & " ").Value

Workbooks.Open "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("B19") / Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("Holdings - Main View").Range("E11")

Cells(index, dateColumn + 1).Value = (Cells(index, dateColumn) - Cells(index, dateColumn + 6)) / Cells(index, dateColumn + 6)

Cells(index, dateColumn + 2).Value = Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("Holdings - Main View").Range("E11")

Cells(index, dateColumn + 3).Value = (Cells(index, dateColumn + 2) - Cells(index, dateColumn + 9)) / Cells(index, dateColumn + 9)



Next index

End Sub
```

Comment: So what's missing is the value of datecolumn?  You want that to be the column corresponding to the date the user entered?

Comment: Exactly, I when I enter the date in the inputbox, I want to select the cell whose value matches the date and assign its column number to dateColumn.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to find the column with a matching header.  For simplicity, here is the brute force approach.  It assumes that the activesheet is the one with the headers and that they are on the first row. Use "datecolumn = matchheader (portfoliodate)" to get the column number

```
Function MatchHeader(strSearch As String) As Long
Dim myRight As Long, Colcount As Long
myRight = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For Colcount = 1 To myRight
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Colcount) = strSearch Then
        MatchHeader = Colcount
        Exit For
    End If
Next Colcount
End Function
```